# What does adding 15 and then applying &~0xf do?

Tags: c++

I have some code I am studying where it is written:

```
(basenameOffset + (basenameTotal+15)) &~0xf
```

why would someone do this? What does it do? I can see that `~0xf` is `0xfffffff0`. Why would you block the last bit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It rounds up to the nearest multiple of 16. Presumably, this is to fix a size for allocating the buffer for the `basename`, whatever it is. :-)

However, if that were what it's for, i.e., deciding how big of a buffer to allocate, then this is not a good strategy. Ideally, you want to expand by a factor of 2 or at least 1.5 each time.

Comment: @DCoder It's nearest upward.

Comment: Aligning to a block size can help reduce fragmentation in memory allocators.

Comment: @ZanLynx I'm not certain that rounding up to 16 will actually make any difference for fragmentation, since even the control structure for many memory allocators would take about that much space. :-P Also, quality allocators will ensure good alignment, without you having to manually do so.

Comment: Yes, allocators do that which is why if you were writing one you would want to use an alignment like that code does. And it does make a difference to fragmentation, by ensuring that the smallest fragment is the block size rather than 1 or 2 bytes.

Comment: I used something like that frequently for SIMD and cache alignment `#define ROUND_UP(x, s) (((x) + (s)-1) & (-(s)))`.  I often allocate an array so that its size is a multiple of the SIMD vector size (4 for SSE and 8 for AVX) i.e. even if I'm only running over 61 elements I make the size 64.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common algorithm to round up to a multiple of a power of two:

```
x = x + (pow2 - 1) & ~(pow2 - 1)
```

It is almost certainly being used to ensure proper alignment. Typically to make SIMD-optimal (16-byte for SSE, 32-byte for AVX, etc.) base addresses and/or to optimize cache usage.